# Where to put HTTP Strict Transport Security in which file Wordpress Bitnami?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am using Wordpress Bitnami via EC2 instance AWS. I installed SSL certificate.

Could you please tell me where I should add HTTP Strict Transport Security line in which file? I am new to it. I don't know if this line is correct for Bitnami.

```
Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

The lines to modify the HEADERS information for WordPress should be placed inside the "Directory" block of the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf` file

```
...
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/>
...
Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
...
</Directory>
```

If you also need to modify the headers settings in different directories, you will need to add a new block for that directory and modify the headers setting

```
...
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-admin>
...
Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
...
</Directory>
```

Then, you will need to restart Apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Comment: `httpd-app.conf` was in `/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/` on my bitnami instance, but editing that file and restarting apache did not add the HSTS header.  I then `sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/` and behold, an `httpd-app.conf` appeared.  I edited it, but still no joy.